# How to compare an input with one object key and value from an array with more objects with more key and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, autocomplete

I am new to coding (one month) and in here and I am a little bit stuck. Creating an autocomplete and i am trying to compare an input with one object key and value from an array with more objects with more key and values.

This is what I have so far. but I am a little bit stuck.

ingredients is the array with more objects where I keep the info

```
$("#ingredientDetails").click(function () {
  var searchQuery = $("input[type = 'text']").val();
  for (var i = 0; i > ingredients.length; i++) {
    if (searchQuery === Object.name(ingredients)) {
      console.log("matching");
    } else {
      console.log("not matching");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `if (searchQuery === Object.name(ingredients))` u means `if (searchQuery === ingredients[i].name)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The loop you are using will not run if you have one or more items in ingredients array as you have used `i > ingredient.length` in your for loop. Try the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
    if (searchQuery === Object.name(ingredients)) {
      console.log("matching");
    } else {
      console.log("not matching");
    }
  }
```